# Internationally issued Visa Credit Card fraudulently used in the US, possibly because merchant bypassed card security features. What are my options?

Tags: united-states, credit-card, india, fraud, visa

My internationally issued credit card was stolen, along with a lot of my personal items in the US. There was also a Apple credit card issued in the US that were stolen, but the fraudulent charges were amicably resolved by the card issuer in this case (Apple says their cards have no PIN attached to it, so it can simply be swiped and used - and so perhaps they also cover for the customer against fraud).

On the other hand, for my internationally issued card (issued outside the US), I had to follow up with the police department in the US, where the robbery took place. The cop painstakingly emailed all the merchants where the card was used, and obtained a response from one Safeway store where it was used - they pulled up a security camera photograph of the woman who used the card at the establishment. But unfortunately the lead dried up there and they couldn't do much else, apart from placing the photographed woman on a watch list.

Now, after several dozen emails to my bank and following all the dispute procedures, the credit card issuing bank managed to reverse $1100 worth of transactions (with no comment on why they were reversed). But there remains another $2000 worth of transactions that remain in dispute. The bank has basically said the following during the course of my interaction with them:

1. "We would like to inform you that upon investigation, we observe from our records that the said charge is secure transaction incurred on **secure merchant web site** and was authenticated using the card credentials which is confidential and known only to the cardholder. In view of the above, we wish to inform you that the said transaction was incurred by an authorized person and hence the transaction remain payable on the card account."
2. To the above response from the bank, I shared the Police Investigation report as proof with them that the card was used at physical merchant establishments in the US like fuel stations, super markets/grocers, restaurants, etc. I also informed them that merchants in the US are known to bypass the security features of the credit cards, and that any card can simply be swiped without the need to enter the secret PIN. Then they changed the response to, "We would like to inform you that upon investigation, we observe from our records that the said charges can be operated only with the **help of physical presence of card**. In view of the above, we wish to inform you that the said transaction was incurred by an authorized person and hence the transaction remain payable on the card account."
3. I tried once more with the bank's highest dispute office, stating that the card was stolen and there is photographic proof with the police in the US, so how could it possibly be an authorized use, and was told this: "Basis your comments expressed we had taken up your query for appropriate review and as an outcome of our investigations, it is observed that the transaction is secured transaction incurred authenticating / using the details which is confidential and known only to the cardholder. In view of the above, we wish to inform you that the said transaction was incurred by an authorized person. In view of the above, we are constrained to conclude that the liability of the said transactions rests with you."

Now there was no way that the person who was going around using my credit card had knowledge of my credit card PIN code. Rather the case has to be that merchants have the capability to bypass the PIN, and there by creating a PIN-less/swipe transaction. The central banking authority of my home country has stringent rules for 2 factor authentication to be enabled for credit cards within the country, but they left a loop hole for transactions that take place outside the country, possibly due to logistical reasons that stop the enforcement of the same.

I have contacted a lawyer in my home country and have sent him the communications to go through. In the meantime, I am trying find evidence that is either published, or an expert of US payments systems who could provide comments that confirm that the US payments system does have the case where credit cards can be swiped bypassing the PIN of the card. If it can be confirmed/proved that this is indeed the case, then the case can be proven that the liability lies with the merchant, since if the PIN less transaction wasn't made possible, the security features of the card would have stopped the fraudulent transaction.

1. Could some with experience about the US credit card payments system, please comment on the simple question: "Can merchant establishments in the US, at their discretion disable the need to enter the PIN of a credit card?"
2. If it so that the merchant can disable the need for a PIN, to authenticate a credit card transaction, can this be the basis for placing the burden of fraud liability on the merchant?
3. Per my research, VISA as a payments processor, promises a 100% fraud protection in the US and UK. So if my bank in India, issues a "International Visa Credit Card", that can be used anywhere in the world, and ended by being fraudulently used in the US, is there any basis to approach Visa, to ask them to enforce their 100% fraud protection promise? Or this is void, since the card was issued in India, and Visa makes no such promises in India?
4. It is likely that I will have go to court against the bank, in such a case what merits do my case have? The bank has been quite shady with their flip-flops from "online merchant website transaction", to "physical card was used". I have never in the 5+ years of having the card made a late payment or used more than 30% of my credit limit, but in this case the cards was maxed out in a few days, and the card issuer made no attempts to block the fraud.

I realize this post has ended up becoming very long. My apologies for the same, and thank you for reading so far. If any one can help me with my above questions, I will be very grateful.

Comment: If someone stole a US issued card, the card itself would have "Card Verification Values" (CVV) These are normally used with the card number in online transactions.  It isn't clear whether your card was issued with CVV printed on the card, but if it was, then this could explain how the charges were made.

Comment: It sounds as though what they are saying is that "online merchant website transactions" occurred and were validated by using details known only to someone physically possessing the card, which for U.S. cards is the CVV printed on the reverse side of the card. As @BrianBorchers mentions, is there a "secret" number printed on the reverse side of your non-U.S. issued credit card?

Comment: Thanks Brian and shoover. Yes, the card has the CVV printed on the back side like most cards. Please read the statements from the bank, in the terms of the rules of the card issuing country (India) - There is a separate user chosen secret PIN which isn't on the card, I believe this is mandatory to be used in the issuing country, but can be bypassed in other countries. This is likely the crux of the issue - proving that the card wasn't used with the PIN, rather due to lack of the need for the PIN to be entered.

Comment: @shoover - Also, all the transactions were in physical stores, fuels stations, restaurants, hotels, grocers like Safeway, etc. So no question of "online merchant website transactions". They are either lying/covering up, or are inept to interpret/explain the term "online", which is a technical terminology from the payment processor lingo and is related to card authentication.

Comment: The US cops were certain there was a certain pattern to these crimes - they steal stuff, pawn it off for drug money, finally the cards get misused at physical merchants across jurisdictions. They don't try to hack into accounts or do stuff online. Low tech crimes.

Comment: It may be relevant - what country are you in? what country was the card issued from (if different from where you live)?

Comment: @Gotham in your country, do you have to type in your PIN (that is *not* printed on the card) every time you use your card in person at a merchant? What about online? In the US you usually never need a PIN (either in person or online), unless you are doing a cash advance from an ATM. I don't even know my PIN anymore.

Comment: Side note, I'm super impressed that the police department you called contacted all the merchants and even got a surveillance video at the grocery store!

Comment: @Freiheit - The card was issued in India, and was stolen and fraudulently used in the US. Does that help you make any comment?

Comment: @TTT Yes, in my country the customer has to enter the PIN (not printed on the card), every time the card is used. For online transactions, only within India, we get a One Time Password on our mobile phones, which have to be entered within 3 minutes, or the transaction fails. 
Regarding your latter statement: "In the US you usually never need a PIN (either in person or online), unless you are doing a cash advance from an ATM. I don't even know my PIN anymore." Do you think I can get a legally authorized person/payments expert to issue that statement? I need it as proof.

Comment: @TTT But this system fails as soon as the card is used outside India. No secret PIN asked, no One TIme Password sent. I find it ridiculous. The bank clearly is in the know.

Comment: @Gotham that's great security, when it's used. Perhaps the US doesn't have the infrastructure in place to do that extra authentication and pause the transaction, but your bank could still ask you within seconds, "Did you just make this purchase? Yes or No."

Comment: @Gotham I assume you could find someone at a bank to attest to something like that. But I don't understand why you need that. Your bank **knows** they didn't ask you to verify those transactions like they do when you're in India. Why does it matter if they *could* have?

Comment: @TTT and others, I scoured the Visa USA website, and found this page with a bunch of documents that basically says, Visa doesn't enforce the merchants to implement any type of "Customer Verification Method" (CVM). https://usa.visa.com/partner-with-us/payment-technology/visa-chip-technology-overview.html

Comment: This document (https://technologypartner.visa.com/Download.aspx?id=574) says when it is an attended Point Of Sale (POS), the "No CVM Required" method is "Recommended". This seems absurd to me. But atleast I have damning evidence now.

Comment: This document (https://usa.visa.com/content/dam/VCOM/regional/na/us/partner-with-us/documents/visa-clarifies-existing-rules.pdf) says there is flexibility of the merchant to implement the EMV system.

Comment: @TTT With regards to your comment about US not having the infrastructure in place for the extra authentication - I think the truth is that US relies on the velocity of payments from consumers to sustain the economy. So Visa as well as the merchants, have a vested interest in making the payment as seemless as possible with minimum "verification" (as seen in the first of two documents). In return they offer 0% liability for the customer on fraud. Trust me, US has better infrastructure, telecommunication systems, and engineering talent than many other dozen countries combined.

Comment: In a country like India, a fraud of even $200 would be able to severely affect a family's financial health. So the regulators have to consider the financial well being of the citizens, over propping up the economy through ultra fast payments. Hence the strict 2 Factor Authentication. I also figure, Visa doesn't offer 0% customer liability for fraud in India.

Comment: @TTT And yes, the police officer was a genuinely hardworking and cooperative person. For what it is worth, it was in the state of Washington. And I heard that all such officers, including those at the DMV in Washington state are much more likely to be polite and amiable.

Comment: In this comment --> "This document (technologypartner.visa.com/Download.aspx?id=574) says when it is an attended Point Of Sale (POS), the "No CVM Required" method is "Recommended". This seems absurd to me. But atleast I have damning evidence now. " The relevant data is on Page 20, Table 2-3. if any is interested.